# Show a route on a map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, gis

How can i show the following result:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=hadera&destination=haifa&sensor=false

on a map? i want to see the entire route!

please: no use of google's javascript API. just the Web Service

Comment: Why don't you want to use the Javascript API?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume you want to show the route on a Google Map, which is [mandatory](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits) ;)

You can do this without using the JavaScript API, just use the [Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) with the `path` parameter containing the encoded polyline you'll find in the `overview_polyline` field of the route of your choice.

Example using the first route (that is, `response.routes[0].overview_polyline.points`) from your sample request:

```
"overview_polyline" : {
    "points" : "en_eEsoctEa@IuAvHzD~@hGrA~D~@i@vCgAlGa@|BqFp[kBOyBAgADk@Hw@JqBb@cIjAcC`@{Cr@iKrC_Bh@kDhAeCx@}Bn@}IpCcFtAq@Hs@D_A?yAEoAQi@OcA]kAg@}OoKmMqIkCgBoBgA}D{Bm@]ERiAxGoA`IYtAs@hCwAzDsB`EoDhGkDrGkBbDmBbD_CrC{@`AcAn@c@Pm@JUDa@?u@Cq@Mo@Um@c@cC}BmGgGgc@yd@qSmTsNiOwDoDqCmBkCuAcA]oC_AyCw@}Bc@_BO{BOwE@aDNiBRyARyBd@_K|Cag@bPsVdImDhAkBf@qCf@_AJqADeABcBCuAIqC_@kIqAuLaBgNmBuImAqFs@kL_BsEq@qEk@eGo@aFUqEIoOSiLI_DAgQQuDIiEa@u\\iDwBOiGw@yB_@uCy@yPsEaIwBiL_D{Cu@sAUgDk@uCYgAIeBCoEAax@nAgC@qCGcBIeCWmKmAmOaBkH_AqCc@}Aa@{CaAaBs@}BiAwMyGoAk@kBcAqHqDcBs@kC}@_D_AwCu@_BUgC[eDSeFIs@A{BFs`AtA_HH}CAoCIwBMsH]sMm@iMm@wG]qDYiFm@eFw@iCg@{Cs@cFsAwI}BqJgC{C{@cKmCuLaDuXmHwT_GuCu@sBc@wGkAqB[kDa@gE]eDQeGO{CCmC@}CFmCHcG\\yLx@wN`AcEXkETyDHiH@_DGgEO_F]sFi@oNuAgP_BwWgCsO{AuCa@eCe@eBa@wBm@uCaA}EwBwBiAaCyAsAaAyDcDoN_NmWqVgA_AiDeCwD_CyAy@wD_BeEyAsBk@kDs@uB]_CYyCU{AIyFOyCGyTW{SYiEEsJQ}ECyA@mDLyFVoCVyBZyCd@aDv@kDdAkA^gAh@qDrAsLtFmInDoBt@oAd@eATcG`AmCLo@Ds@?oCEeAG{lB_VaM{AyGs@aHYuISeB?gHMiLYyJe@gO{AwCUwGs@yf@_FaFc@u@KqI{@{Iy@wEa@{De@gO{AqC]mHk@gEOoPUoOQ_S[kKOmBIkBWs@Q}@[}@e@eAy@{AkBoAgBqDmHi@eAs@_Ae@e@sAaAcAm@_Ac@}@U_AM_BK}BM]@eCEyBJaALs@LsA\\_Bv@{BlAiBhAyAx@{Ap@wCtAaFjC_CfAwBv@cB\\kDt@_LnBwJbBmEb@gJp@M@{BLcD`@cDX}E`@_CLuBCcEWmKk@{Dg@cCYaEgAqCoAoBwAcCgC}EmGg@m@gDkEuE{FiBwBoBsCkAwB}@wBo@gCa@sCMqAMoD@uIBkDFuQ@qDBy@"
},
```

Resulting map:

[image: Driving directions from Hadera to Haifa]

Full request, requires URL-encoding the encoded polyline:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=400x400&path=weight:3%7Ccolor:red%7Cenc:en_eEsoctEa%40IuAvHzD~%40hGrA~D~%40i%40vCgAlGa%40%7CBqFp%5BkBOyBAgADk%40Hw%40JqBb%40cIjAcC%60%40%7BCr%40iKrC_Bh%40kDhAeCx%40%7DBn%40%7DIpCcFtAq%40Hs%40D_A%3FyAEoAQi%40OcA%5DkAg%40%7DOoKmMqIkCgBoBgA%7DD%7BBm%40%5DERiAxGoA%60IYtAs%40hCwAzDsB%60EoDhGkDrGkBbDmBbD_CrC%7B%40%60AcAn%40c%40Pm%40JUDa%40%3Fu%40Cq%40Mo%40Um%40c%40cC%7DBmGgGgc%40yd%40qSmTsNiOwDoDqCmBkCuAcA%5DoC_AyCw%40%7DBc%40_BO%7BBOwE%40aDNiBRyARyBd%40_K%7CCag%40bPsVdImDhAkBf%40qCf%40_AJqADeABcBCuAIqC_%40kIqAuLaBgNmBuImAqFs%40kL_BsEq%40qEk%40eGo%40aFUqEIoOSiLI_DAgQQuDIiEa%40u%5CiDwBOiGw%40yB_%40uCy%40yPsEaIwBiL_D%7BCu%40sAUgDk%40uCYgAIeBCoEAax%40nAgC%40qCGcBIeCWmKmAmOaBkH_AqCc%40%7DAa%40%7BCaAaBs%40%7DBiAwMyGoAk%40kBcAqHqDcBs%40kC%7D%40_D_AwCu%40_BUgC%5BeDSeFIs%40A%7BBFs%60AtA_HH%7DCAoCIwBMsH%5DsMm%40iMm%40wG%5DqDYiFm%40eFw%40iCg%40%7BCs%40cFsAwI%7DBqJgC%7BC%7B%40cKmCuLaDuXmHwT_GuCu%40sBc%40wGkAqB%5BkDa%40gE%5DeDQeGO%7BCCmC%40%7DCFmCHcG%5CyLx%40wN%60AcEXkETyDHiH%40_DGgEO_F%5DsFi%40oNuAgP_BwWgCsO%7BAuCa%40eCe%40eBa%40wBm%40uCaA%7DEwBwBiAaCyAsAaAyDcDoN_NmWqVgA_AiDeCwD_CyAy%40wD_BeEyAsBk%40kDs%40uB%5D_CYyCU%7BAIyFOyCGyTW%7BSYiEEsJQ%7DECyA%40mDLyFVoCVyBZyCd%40aDv%40kDdAkA%5EgAh%40qDrAsLtFmInDoBt%40oAd%40eATcG%60AmCLo%40Ds%40%3FoCEeAG%7BlB_VaM%7BAyGs%40aHYuISeB%3FgHMiLYyJe%40gO%7BAwCUwGs%40yf%40_FaFc%40u%40KqI%7B%40%7BIy%40wEa%40%7BDe%40gO%7BAqC%5DmHk%40gEOoPUoOQ_S%5BkKOmBIkBWs%40Q%7D%40%5B%7D%40e%40eAy%40%7BAkBoAgBqDmHi%40eAs%40_Ae%40e%40sAaAcAm%40_Ac%40%7D%40U_AM_BK%7DBM%5D%40eCEyBJaALs%40LsA%5C_Bv%40%7BBlAiBhAyAx%40%7BAp%40wCtAaFjC_CfAwBv%40cB%5CkDt%40_LnBwJbBmEb%40gJp%40M%40%7BBLcD%60%40cDX%7DE%60%40_CLuBCcEWmKk%40%7BDg%40cCYaEgAqCoAoBwAcCgC%7DEmGg%40m%40gDkEuE%7BFiBwBoBsCkAwB%7D%40wBo%40gCa%40sCMqAMoD%40uIBkDFuQ%40qDBy%40

Comment: wow!amazing, a solution!
Thanks miguev :)
1 - how would i implement this? i get the entire diretions' json and then?
2. can't I show the route on a dynamic map?

Comment: I've no idea what platform you're working on, but I imagine you have some server-side runtime environment (e.g. PHP) that allows you to sent HTTP requests anywhere (from the server) and process its responses to then deliver something back to the browser. If you want to use a dynamic map, then you'll have to use the Google Maps JavaScript API V3 (technically not the only way, but currently the only reasonable one) to show a map with the same polyline.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer, being the closest to what I've imagined.  thanks miguev

Answer (score 0):

how about [google's support for embedding](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72644)? 
or [how to add google maps to your website](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/additional-options.html)

the easiest way to use it is go to actual google maps and use the link button, then use the link in your site/whatever