# Google Maps API: Draw a route using points of a polyline

Tags: google-maps, google-polyline, google-directory-api

I'm using google directions to get the main route between two points and it's alternatives (3) so each alternative contains steps and also the overview polyline resultant of all that steps so I want to draw those 3 polylines in a map to see the the main route and the alternatives, do you know how to do that?

This is one of the overview polylines

```
"overview_polyline": {
    "points": "uiyqBfb~zQgGwAgCtM}DfVpDrBeBbFqDjFmHfXkOzh@cKxNuGlW_BzSiJxZcBfHuS~NqK`Ia@lFgIpC{fAoDcW~BmEbBeqAmIaEoBgB{KB}J}OoJcBwAeHuAwDaBkCnCwKjLcNgBkIc@oDtD}EhG{GjAgVcDsN{Bm@|FaAvOiE|Va`@xw@}Jh]dPhcArEzQuIpXkMna@sDbPb@fGdDxE|O~E~ZzH`ThQtdA|jA|NfRxC~Jc@p[iEd`@WbSvKza@rTlf@~ArMfFtJrChOjQfM~JzX@~VnOn]g@jMcBdLkGzHg@|DyGfEcEjLgEvHaKoAgNiEoLsCoKUkUz@_CtBqI?eDhAeGeDsIRyK`IqIfIkPtEuUbNcLpOuPpZ]rHpHtQpLnOlEvIEpJfId[pShc@z@th@cLx@yNnGk`@rVsLfLm|@v|@_VxKgZ`XmR~VeH~^~@jIsAvLeD~LiCre@mGhP}Eda@D`YqBt[aIna@iI|Db@pENpDtAzCc@pG{@bFuQlGcLxGuUz@}PhBUhIcD`Eof@rMwUfEk^|Ck}@tFcMjDiP~GeN`RcF]}CxBmEc@{BvAoGdCsKpFmOgEuB\\eEjKjB~GwGvBiDsDgEyGwD`JeDTgCyGuCOcGvFmGzJeC_DwCa@WvM{@rC_CJuHoIiFEgBwC{HeJuCm@sAxAf@fFoBvBmDx@iNm@mCxD{DkAwMrDcJrF}IhSsDbB{D{AyY_CoK~AuP`@uPm@eKbC}Lq@eNsCeDeC_Jj@wIb@mEr@eHgBiGoKiGyJeDgI}CmHG{KiCyO}P}IgNkNaUoKkCkDYiB{Bg@sFwAaDeDsSwT}PY{KaEeIBqTfEiEeEgDkLyUyIkT}BoP{DyGiGwHiW{Is^kOiScLmTeIqGsPcTqD_FgMaDwNqMwOuVqHy\\yFkMmGwEaHeAqBmCr@aU_CiBoSpDyHBkH}Kc[kTq[mPyYiOyVyR_Sc\\{ZsRwfA{]wh@oPaNVyIiFeHKmE~AqAhEwNgDiNmFgL~H}Cs@oIxH{DRsFqG_FoA}GfEgP~MuFi@}Sh@yDdDgInBaGh@w[cCwH~AeGeFeLcUD_LkAiDwUaJuMXaQuGyBgB|LkLhL{JnPoGhIuQfACz@kEqCgBF}F~@qL{AaHa@qJCcHiAsBeH]{PiHeJoCu@{BxCwC[cFiVePaGt@}KoH_NyMyNiGyWwMeIgFiLmIod@lEoSaf@eIrF{@oG}C_@{B{CsEmAmDgCcAoL_AaFs@oCl@mD\\eMkHkFaJqFkEiPN}HrBvKdEzExA|FJJ"
  },
```

Comment: related question: [google maps static map polyline passing through lakes, river, mountains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255380/google-maps-static-map-polyline-passing-through-lakes-river-mountains)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `decodePath` function of the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#encoding) to decode the encoded points to use as the path of a Polyline.

```
  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(json.overview_polyline.points),
    map: map
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5whLfvx1/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var json = {
  "overview_polyline": {
    "points": "uiyqBfb~zQgGwAgCtM}DfVpDrBeBbFqDjFmHfXkOzh@cKxNuGlW_BzSiJxZcBfHuS~NqK`Ia@lFgIpC{fAoDcW~BmEbBeqAmIaEoBgB{KB}J}OoJcBwAeHuAwDaBkCnCwKjLcNgBkIc@oDtD}EhG{GjAgVcDsN{Bm@|FaAvOiE|Va`@xw@}Jh]dPhcArEzQuIpXkMna@sDbPb@fGdDxE|O~E~ZzH`ThQtdA|jA|NfRxC~Jc@p[iEd`@WbSvKza@rTlf@~ArMfFtJrChOjQfM~JzX@~VnOn]g@jMcBdLkGzHg@|DyGfEcEjLgEvHaKoAgNiEoLsCoKUkUz@_CtBqI?eDhAeGeDsIRyK`IqIfIkPtEuUbNcLpOuPpZ]rHpHtQpLnOlEvIEpJfId[pShc@z@th@cLx@yNnGk`@rVsLfLm|@v|@_VxKgZ`XmR~VeH~^~@jIsAvLeD~LiCre@mGhP}Eda@D`YqBt[aIna@iI|Db@pENpDtAzCc@pG{@bFuQlGcLxGuUz@}PhBUhIcD`Eof@rMwUfEk^|Ck}@tFcMjDiP~GeN`RcF]}CxBmEc@{BvAoGdCsKpFmOgEuB\\eEjKjB~GwGvBiDsDgEyGwD`JeDTgCyGuCOcGvFmGzJeC_DwCa@WvM{@rC_CJuHoIiFEgBwC{HeJuCm@sAxAf@fFoBvBmDx@iNm@mCxD{DkAwMrDcJrF}IhSsDbB{D{AyY_CoK~AuP`@uPm@eKbC}Lq@eNsCeDeC_Jj@wIb@mEr@eHgBiGoKiGyJeDgI}CmHG{KiCyO}P}IgNkNaUoKkCkDYiB{Bg@sFwAaDeDsSwT}PY{KaEeIBqTfEiEeEgDkLyUyIkT}BoP{DyGiGwHiW{Is^kOiScLmTeIqGsPcTqD_FgMaDwNqMwOuVqHy\\yFkMmGwEaHeAqBmCr@aU_CiBoSpDyHBkH}Kc[kTq[mPyYiOyVyR_Sc\\{ZsRwfA{]wh@oPaNVyIiFeHKmE~AqAhEwNgDiNmFgL~H}Cs@oIxH{DRsFqG_FoA}GfEgP~MuFi@}Sh@yDdDgInBaGh@w[cCwH~AeGeFeLcUD_LkAiDwUaJuMXaQuGyBgB|LkLhL{JnPoGhIuQfACz@kEqCgBF}F~@qL{AaHa@qJCcHiAsBeH]{PiHeJoCu@{BxCwC[cFiVePaGt@}KoH_NyMyNiGyWwMeIgFiLmIod@lEoSaf@eIrF{@oG}C_@{B{CsEmAmDgCcAoL_AaFs@oCl@mD\\eMkHkFaJqFkEiPN}HrBvKdEzExA|FJJ"
  }
};

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(json.overview_polyline.points),
    map: map
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < polyline.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(polyline.getPath().getAt(i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Viewed 9k times. The answer is 4 years _old_ and provides a full functioning code where only the polyline points have to be replaced to see how the route for the own points looks like and only 1 up vote? I don't understand it. My +1 as it really helped and saved me hours!

Answer (score 1):

you should declare your path and then declare the polyline like this :

```
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
    {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
    {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
    {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
```