# Google Directions API limited versus Google Directions Javascript.API

Tags: google-maps

If I make a request via javascript, I get a JSON object returned that has Routes, Legs, Steps ,and Path data, the latter being a  set of Lat,Lng co-ordinates along the step.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?...query for the javascript and then using the directionsService function

If I make a request server-side, with exactly the same request, I only get Routes, Legs and Steps data returned, no Path data.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/json?...query

Has anyone else experienced this? are there any workarounds? Uisng the other URL in each application just returns a 404.

Comment: related question: [google maps static map polyline passing through lakes, river, mountains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255380/google-maps-static-map-polyline-passing-through-lakes-river-mountains)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract path data from the polyline property of the step:

> polyline contains a single points object that holds an encoded polyline representation of the step. This polyline is an approximate (smoothed) path of the step.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsResponseElements

[image]

Encoded polyline algorithm is described here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm

Google Maps JavaScript API has a static method in geometry library to decode the encoded polyline:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#encoding

For Android apps you can use Google Maps Android API utility library that contains polyline decoding and encoding functions:

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

Google Maps iOS SDK also has static method to obtain a path from encoded polyline:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_path

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Xomena,
I spent yesterday decoding the individual polyline fragments into a <LIST> and then re-encoding, and it works just as you said. The last lat, lng pair of each polyline is the same as the first of the next step, and so there's a tiny amount of duplication which creates no problems, but which could be tidied up.

Thank you,
Greg