# html2canvas is not working properly while taking snap of a div containing gmap (Google Map)

Tags: javascript, image, angular, canvas, html2canvas

I'm am converting a div containing google map inside to image but it is not showing as it was.

I'm using angular4.

My original image was as follows:

[image: original div]

but after converting with html2canvas shows as follows:

[image]

My code for conversion is as follows:

```
html2Cnv(){
    let self = this;
    let mycnvHtml: HTMLVideoElement = self.mycnvHtml.nativeElement;
    html2canvas(mycnvHtml, {
      onrendered: function(canvas1) {
        canvas1.toBlob((blob: Blob)=>{
          let file = new File([blob], 'msr-' + (new Date).toISOString().replace(/:|\./g, '-') + '.webm', {
            type: 'image/png'
          });
          self.fileShare.addFile(file);
          self.onDone.emit(file);
        }, "image/png");
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: the problem was discussed here https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/345. Maybe this question is related to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046778/html2canvas-does-not-work-with-google-maps-pan/24281734#24281734

Comment: any alternate for it?

Comment: You may want to look at creating a static map with a polyline plotted on it, look here for inspiration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302858/google-static-maps-with-directions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of converting div containing google map to canvas I followed following steps and I reached closed to my requirement except it didn't gave route

> Original div [image]
>   After Conversion [image]

1. Get URL of Map

   `getCordDistance() {
       let radlat1 = Math.PI * this.locStart.lat/180;
       let radlat2 = Math.PI * this.locEnd.lat/180;
       let theta = this.locStart.lng-this.locEnd.lng;
       let radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
       let dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
       dist = Math.acos(dist);
       dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
       dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
       /*if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
       if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }*/
       return dist 
     }`

   `getImgUrl(cll){
       let dist=this.getCordDistance();
       let comn={
         lat:((this.locStart.lat+this.locEnd.lat)/2),
         lng:((this.locStart.lng+this.locEnd.lng)/2)
       };
       try {
         let ppp=document.getElementById('map456');
         this.dynamicImg='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?' +
           'center=' +comn.lat+','+comn.lng +
           '&zoom='+(dist<1?15:dist>1800?3:dist>900?4:this.mapRef.getZoom())+
           '&size='+ppp.offsetWidth+'x'+ppp.offsetHeight +
           '&maptype=roadmap'+
           '&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C'+this.locStart.lat+','+this.locStart.lng +
           '&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C'+this.locEnd.lat+','+this.locEnd.lng +
           '&key=myKey';
       }catch(er){console.log(er)}
       if(cll){
         cll()
       }
     }`
2. Do an ajax request to get image blob if you just need image of map

   `html2Cnv(){
       let self = this;
       this.getImgUrl(()=>{
         let oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
         oReq.open("GET", this.dynamicImg, true);
         oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
         oReq.onload =(oEvent)=>{
           let blob = new Blob([oReq.response], {type: "image/png"});
           let file = new File([blob], 'msr-' + (new Date).toISOString().replace(/:|\./g, '-') + '.webm', {
             type: 'image/png'
           });
           self.fileShare.addFile(file);
           self.onDone.emit(file);
         };
         oReq.send();
       });
     }`
3. Else create a duplicate content same as the div we want to take screenshot but in place of google map create an img tag with src as found in first step

   `html2Cnv(){
       let self = this;
       this.getImgUrl(()=>{
         html2canvas(this.canvas1, {
           onrendered: function(canvas1) {
             canvas1.toBlob((blob: Blob)=>{
               let file = new File([blob], 'msr-' + (new Date).toISOString().replace(/:|\./g, '-') + '.webm', {
                 type: 'image/png'
               });
               self.fileShare.addFile(file);
               self.onDone.emit(file);
             }, "image/png");
           }
         });
       })
     }`