# google static maps with enc path is not always working

Tags: google-maps-static-api

i have implement a static map that show a route based on

```
routes[0]->overview_polyline
```

and i also have add the start and end markers

The problem is that is not always working and i assume that there is a problem with overview_polyline but i can not figure out

This is a working static map that show both markets and route

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=650x400&path=enc:q|wfFs}yoCuEhLyC`Gk@rI{@pLoF|LyEiAaHrE{VlPzAxNsAnK{Plc@gl@jbAon@|sAuN~b@uRr\}Rl\iIxWbCr}@fG`d@iJnp@{Ez]v@nhA~ItjAgGzn@}Ib[wQfAit@vAcf@rOig@h\wWpc@ie@~uAmF~aAtRrbAsLdVgZf_@_LjrAuEjp@^|_@n^fr@`_@pi@h\|Z|y@|`@rRhZ?~a@sGz\nLjiB~Yh`Cvr@vqBjc@`qAf^xoBvXfoAp|@bdBht@xwAhC~ZqAb^aGlt@fHbe@jp@rfAfE`a@oBna@cMlr@aXljATnx@xIbp@dA~r@_Ghm@jKds@`O~z@nAj|@tP`h@|nAvrCz]fw@hIx^nLzu@|Nz[jZjl@vh@ndAny@n_Btv@n}AQfl@{Rfm@wTl`@eQdv@Cni@nGjb@zL|k@~Afj@iCva@eJblDrE`n@`Mbe@eAxUiJxTHj\`Oh_@nRtcA?lWsJpq@wJfy@w@rt@pG|w@zGfh@`FfqCpSl{BnWvzAxLt{@tD~}@]`|@cGxj@}Ujy@_Uv^yUt|@oHdk@{^xbBap@jkB{\bu@gYd`@wd@`c@}_@`Wid@lR_b@rD}SfU{b@rXgh@p[wVw@giAZe\{BwNXq^xNm|@~^em@nd@uiAr{Au_@hrA}Zf}@g]p}@eKp^eBxd@wGrWcQjPwNbP{ElV}o@v}Bl@hh@cArn@cO`d@mNv^wBnU}Wtw@sM|[yAvTyKl^ae@|y@mM|k@aOb`@cGvd@{Wr}Agr@foAkk@p}@ij@pw@aZfr@^lm@hAzbAd\lkB{Krs@oMrXeNpj@}Jh`AbCpQfS`s@`Avj@_]``Cwh@rbA?hc@wTty@iSffAs]`n@{Xd\cg@zb@ai@lhAc@n_AyBlpAwCfx@~Frd@xNpb@y@~kAsFjZuYn_@uFp[v@fZcGjs@{F`j@cGdxAeXjyA{Kx{@}HjaAiAde@sOr[}IvzAe[`c@iNpNu[h^mM`ZmNlXgJfY{ZfeAwWzkA}h@rjAqt@j}Ak]j]qr@j\qk@dTg\`g@wNtJuWzUma@n~@iUpd@_Wz[iE~S{Gld@yEpMuRzIuVpNmp@nvAeYll@{_@vWuNtZaa@jq@oYv_@qf@tsA}Nli@mAlXeHd|@xHv^uAjx@lLl\|Bhf@iCli@xGpi@}If{@fFn[d@py@uFd|@vCftAq@h`@vBhb@tB`m@jUrj@rZ|WrOjb@rJji@rPte@h`@f|@dq@lwAjXtm@dY|^ti@|m@veAzbAb}@ri@fKxH_CtQ^f@bWzHlQfPrQzY&markers=color:green|label:A|37.9746479,23.73097699999994&markers=color:red|label:B|38.24670270000001,21.7345758000000162
```

This route is not working

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=650x400&path=enc:q|wfFs…n@y@zHc@hCg@jCmASUnDUbDc@tGWzCEp@MxBSnBCRM?uDlCkA{AY_@[c@IHmAjA[^e@Z}At@aC`BeIvFu@^cBfA{GlEKF\fCb@lDXpBJhAE~@[rBMv@c@bDgAvIW~@aA~BKPcBjDoAbCsA~BeCrDeEnG}D~GmDdGeE~G}F~J{B~D}DzGUNUZ_A~AaHjLIXAf@Bf@H^^t@FR@PbDrDpDvEbAlAjAvApD`E~@`A`KrLX\v@|@vCjDr@t@`Av@rKxGnEpCfFjDtHdFbC~AhAn@lFdD~E~CpMjIzBtAn@b@lIpFlC~A\LnBp@j@JbAFrB?|Ba@bBm@vBkAdG}C`@WvBwAxAgAxAaAbAk@p@Wp@Mz@G^AdAHpCt@t@Vh@V|J`DlHbCpKnDbBd@lB^~Bd@rCr@|HzBzIhCfAXfAP`F^z@FbEVhDJnJFlGBjC@d@Ln@?ZHb@V^j@Jb@Fr@?bA?bGEpBAzNE|DPzK@zAAr@KfASx@a@z@mDbGyGfLeBzCs@~Am@fB{@bE_@|Bw@dJ]xENd@@l@FbBDz@DN`@P`Bx@lCtAlD~AdAd@vA|@vIhHvAdA^Vx@n@CH&markers=color:green|label:A|37.9746479,23.73097699999994&markers=color:red|label:B|37.9429712,23.646971099999973
```

Its only displays the markers without the route

i have implement the code from here 
[Google static maps with directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302858/google-static-maps-with-directions)

Can any help me make this work, any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I check the encoded polyline from the second example in the Interactive Polyline encoder utility

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility

I can see that the route is located somewhere in the sea as shown in the screenshot

[image]

Can you post the original Directions API request that returns this encoded polyline, please?

Comment: Sorry for the delay but i had reached the max places quota and i could not reproduce the problem.Here is the request {origin: "Athens, Central Athens, Greece", destination: "Pireas, Piraeus, Greece", travelMode: "DRIVING"}.I hope this helps, feel free to ask more details.

Comment: thanks for your time.I found that the problem was on console.log.I printed out the static map url thought console.log and because of too many chars added 3dots ... and the path was not valid.Your answer helped me to search why enc path in in the sea and i found it