# Map/Directions Cards & Integrate Actions/Intents such as CALL, EMAIL - With Dialogflow, Actions on Google, NodeJS Client V2

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have been trying to figure out how to construct Maps/Directions Cards using **Dialogflow** and the **NodeJS Client**.

After doing a little bit of research, I found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302858/google-static-maps-with-directions) that explains how to generate a static map URL (as an image) using **Google Directions API** and Polylines. But in my opinion, there should be a feature in Dialogflow that allows developers to build those types of cards, along with associated built-in **Intents or Events** such as **CALL**, **EMAIL**, **DIRECTIONS**, etc.

Below is an example of what I am trying to build:

[image]

[image]

Below is a piece of code that I wrote, trying to reproduce the call to actions (Call, Email, Directions, etc). I am also aware of follow-up [actions types](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/ActionType) but I am not sure how to make it work within my app (How to trigger call/email events?)

```
function triggerAction(conv) {

        let actions = ['Call','Fax','Directions', 'Website'];
        conv.ask(new BasicCard({
            text: `Some description`, // Note the two spaces before '\n' required for
            // a line break to be rendered in the card.
            subtitle: 'This is a subtitle',
            title: 'Title: this is a title',
            buttons: new Button({
                title: 'This is a button',
                url: 'https://assistant.google.com/',
            }),
            image: new Image({
                url: IMG_URL_AOG,
                alt: 'Image alternate text',
            }),
        }));

        conv.ask(new Suggestions(actions));
  }
```

I also created those intents within the Dialogflow dashboard as follow-up intents.
In short, I want a user to be able to tap one of these buttons and trigger an action, such as CALL, EMAIL, etc. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I may have missed it (if so, I apologize), but is there a question here? If so, can you make it clear what you've tried and what didn't work? Or what you're trying to do that you couldn't?

Comment: I guess my question is about  

1- How to build these types of cards (see screenshots), using Dialogflow & the Nodejs Client.   

2-How to configure "Click to call event", "Click to email event", "Click to get directions event", etc.

The piece of code I share below is my starting point. I'm now trying to figure out how to properly create those events (within Dialogflow) and make them work in harmony with the Nodejs Client.  

You don't have to apologize for anything. I really appreciate you taking the help me sort this out.

I hope I was clear enough. If not please get back to me.