# Phone Number in Google Actions (Google Assistant) Response

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I'm building a conversation on Google Assistant for smart phones. In one of the dialogs, I'm providing a phone number as a response but this phone number is rendered as text.

Is there a way to provide a "click to call" phone number in Google Assistant response?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, but you may have some workarounds.

First, keep in mind that the Assistant is meant to be multi-platform with a voice focus. Although it has a screen and touch controls, it is meant to be used by voice. Even with touch controls, these aren't guaranteed to be on a phone - Smart Displays will likely have these controls, yet not be able to make phone calls.

That said, you may be able to display a [Basic Card](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card) that includes a link. This link could be to a `tel:` URL which contains the telephone number and, on appropriate devices, would make the call.

I would have also suggested a Link-Out Suggestion, but [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#linkoutsuggestion) for that seems to suggest that the Android Intent you trigger needs to be one that you have control over.

Comment: When I first started working with the Assistant, one of the first feature that I wanted to build was CALL/TEXT/EMAIL feature. Unfortunately it looks like this feature is not built-in.

I strongly believe it should be added to the assistant. What is the point of having an assistant if it can't place phone calls, send text messages or emails on the user's behalf? In my opinion, It should have been among the first feature to build in the assistant. Here is my original SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917405/map-directions-cards-integrate-actions-intents-such-as-call-email-with-dial

Comment: I have already tried "tel" schema but only http and https protocols are supported for urls in Basic Card and Link Out Suggestions.