# Custom Rich Response Cards - possible?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am interested in building my own cards (since there isn't any such card that is currently available..?), similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917405/map-directions-cards-integrate-actions-intents-such-as-call-email-with-dial?rq=1). However no one answered that question previously.

If not, how else can we achieve [deep-linking to open other apps](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#calling_the_helper_3) (like for example I want to get directions, I don't mind having to open up Google Maps to do so). But it only seems to work for Android, and it is still in Developer Preview..?

I also want to allow the user to click on a card / a button and call a mobile number, but url only takes in http / https URL schemes and not tel://, so that workaround can't work...

[image: What I want to achieve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't build your own rich response types, they are internal features of the Dialogflow platform and the Assistant apps, you can only use them as far as Google exposes them via the APIs. You are not alone in wanting to have more advanced rich responses (I'd like to have free-form HTML cards), but waiting is all you can do here.

Comment: Dang. Thanks for confirming. Any workarounds to get the call feature and directions feature at least? :(

Comment: Well, as for Maps the workaround would be to include a normal link (which can contain [directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action)) and have it open in the users browser. As for calling I don't really see a plausible solution other than waiting for Google to make it available to everyone.

Comment: If you are not averse to the user clicking twice, you could link to a mobile friendly web page that has the dial button on it.  Perhaps the linked web page could even "auto-dial" via javascript and then you could just label the link "dial" and the user might not notice the interstitial.