# Maps image download error, routes are not coming in the image

Tags: php, file-get-contents, php-curl

I created a function in PHP that downloads a map created in google maps, I am able to download, however, the route is not coming when I am saving.

How the picture is coming:

[image]

How it should come:

[image]

Code:

```
function download_remote_file_with_curl($file_url, $save_to) {
    $arrContextOptions = array(
        "ssl" => array(
            "verify_peer" => false,
            "verify_peer_name" => false,
        ),
    );

    $response = file_get_contents($file_url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
    //echo $response;
    //file_put_contents($save_to, $response);
    $downloaded_file = fopen($save_to, 'wb');
    fwrite($downloaded_file, $response);
    fclose($downloaded_file);
}


$urlDownload = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=1000x1000&maptype=roadmap&path=enc:zklaAbqcyJzCmF~@b@fBdAzCiEnKyQlFpCnMdH~_@nU~JlFlCNrw@oL~IcApEZxd@nQpgBhq@tRtStgA``Aty@`o@ll@pa@tNhFzMvJfG~D|Y~Hxd@rMll@`Rtb@jLjNzExWtFz`@bJvM|ItG`LdF|V`GvD|CL|JiBv]aGld@cHrk@cLdU_Fpb@wGdMg@vaAqAti@g@z_@Cj~A{@raAfDlp@xAfYa@tyAuDtVEbTdApO`@rGk@dP`@vgEo@baCuA`|AaArHGIzAwCtHqDlNf@rl@lA~bAnAphAMj`@hBlj@\hd@s@tL\pHnCff@~A`|@lMnmEnBbKrFbDn`@jP~RtQ~k@hVhNtGb@xFgPheAsAnOuIlaBpj@|qCtDzGb`A~`AzDvGd@vI{Af_@x@~GxItHzLvGp\fLxc@t\pe@d`@h|AnmA`WvQnEDnF}Bd\uUjGeB~Gb@nEvB~KnMri@ni@fjCbfCpmArkAv|@pz@bjAjhApcEt}Ddx@pv@r_@lZzyB|hBtoHneGzZvVh|@xq@fb@jZh^fZjD~E`FlOzMbc@|L|`@hQrS~H`MhQ~w@hEdzB~B~hAbAbk@Ux^kNx~BeGriAaCbe@|@zSt@`ChDnBnZlAlFtCl`@`AzMpBpRvJlKvFbKlLxd@pcAdk@~oAjbAbiAnPxLfq@b^ndDpkBbdDfjBbqAdt@hFjAtNhCfMbD|g@tYhxDfxBrqFx~C|CpCzA|EE~E}i@raDsOb}@uO~{@{f@zvCr@hG~CdDf`Bly@hL|Lt@bClD|Brx@naAvAnAzb@lg@zj@veDjMbI|rBhdAlJzFdAjCbBpgBpMlsQdIhhO]p^?hb@z@dsAp@jo@l@pWffDp`FzyB~eDxdEhlGpNrSvv@hn@duEvuDnsJp~HtpLvvJ~bBtvAjw@hp@hDnFnHvpBlSh}FrFd_BvAno@tu@buTtPxwEnXvhJbRddGbQ~nGlNjqFlJv~BvC~rAdFppBvNhvEhShsGw@nQ}i@htBsq@lgCcJd]}BjPkG|y@gPptBu]byE_H~gArB`EfG|FxXnYfv@nv@nWhX`RjRjHj`@bfBdgKlCrKzGhQp`@lbAtdBnjEr_@z`A`~@n}Bth@fuAdpDzdJ|W`o@`ClAxIj@beA~A~p@bAx|F~I`lEzGvwAbCdMx@neDjlAbp@hUrE}@prB_qCzBaAjJAxOKhWfAfP?tm@}Q~{Bkr@r{EeyAxPoApfB~WzK|AHTdBDrO}A~RmBrXsCzZuA~NJx@bD|@dAfX`@{@nG&markers=color:green|label:A|-10.8819552,-61.95483539999998&markers=color:red|label:B|-12.457280801085,-64.2310285267651&key=yourkey";
download_remote_file_with_curl($urlDownload, realpath('C:/test') . '/' . 'test' . '.jpg');
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302858/google-static-maps-with-directions

Comment: I'm not having an error in plotting the map, but in downloading

Comment: Start by properly URL-encoding the value of your path parameter, because it doesn't look like you did that at all.

Comment: Did you test the URL to know? You have to put the maps key at the end

Comment: I don't need to test this to see that you did not URL-encode this value, because multiple un-encoded characters are visible right at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what I'm about to write makes sense, but the route that you want to download is an item that appears once it's selected.

For example when the "SKIP" buttom in Youtube appears to quit an advertisement, it creates an instance of that box in HTML, and then it dissappears when Add is over.

I think that the route is this kind of instance and you must add a line of code to also take that piece of html

Comment: The image is static, the route also