# Custom Map to show on API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am trying to show a race course via the google api. I have gone in and created a [custom map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/support) and can't figure out how to show that from the api. I am trying to add this to a website and then want to add another API on top of it.

[This is the map I have created](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1NLv4DtgAA2edAYM_48Q4qkFT1dI&ll=39.55169386746729%2C-110.92371567871095&z=8)

[image: Google MyMaps screenshot]

Comment: Are you trying to style a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map like you have a static map?  Could you please clarify what you currently have (a link to the static map documentation doesn't particularly help) and what you  are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am new to this and trying to learn the programming. I have gone in and pulled the api for google maps and am able to place a single point on the map but I cannot create an entire route. My end goal is to be able to have all of these routes show on a map where I can then pull an api feed from spot.com and place my current location on this map.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you currently have and describe what you are trying to add and what you have tried to do to add it.  The documentation has pretty good examples in it.

Comment: This is the map I have created (https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1NLv4DtgAA2edAYM_48Q4qkFT1dI&ll=39.55169386746729%2C-110.92371567871095&z=8) When I go to pull the google api it does not add these routes to the map. So I want to know how to get those routes to show up on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display data from [Google MyMaps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/) on a [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) map, export the data as KML/KMZ, then display it using [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml)

related questions:

- [Importing myMaps data in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484814/importing-mymaps-data-in-google-maps)
- [Render a My Maps using Google Maps JavaScript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533307/render-a-my-maps-using-google-maps-javascript-api)

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=1NLv4DtgAA2edAYM_48Q4qkFT1dI)

[image: KmlLayer screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this question with `google-static-maps`, you may also be interested in:

- [Issue 207:  KML layer in Static Maps API](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=207)
- [Show a route on a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015791/show-a-route-on-a-map/9024450#9024450)